# Can a neural net with hidden layers model functions that one without can't?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know that the hidden layers help in extracting features from the input for effective classification by the output layer but can it also help in adding modeling capacity to the network.

Comment: Of course! It is the fundamental theorem of NNs. To be able to approximate any continuous function, the NN needs hidden layers with non-linear activation functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

It can, **if** the activation function is non-linear. If each layer simply computes a linear transformation of the output of the previous layer, then those transformations simply stack to another linear transformation. That is, if we have $y = VWx$, where $x$ is the input to the network, $W$ are the input weights to the first layer, and $V$ are the weights between the first and second layer, then alternatively, we could define a matrix $A=VW$ which would do the computation in one go as $y=Ax$.

In terms of the number of nodes you'd need, say the input has dimension $K\times1$, the first layer has $M$ nodes (such that $W$ has size $M\times K$) and the second layer has $N$ nodes (such that $V$ has size $N\times M$), then the composite matrix $A=VW$ would have size $N\times K$. So from this we can see that the original two-layer linear network can be replaced by a single-layer linear network with $N$ units.

With a non-linear activation function, we instead have $y=f(Vf(Wx))$ and so we cannot apply this trick - we will always need two layers to perform this computation.